# Laguerre interpolation algorithm, something's wrong with my implementation

Tags: c++, math, polynomial-math

This is a problem I have been struggling for a week, coming back just to give up after wasted hours...

I am supposed to find coefficents for the following Laguerre polynomial:

```
P0(x) = 1

P1(x) = 1 - x

Pn(x) = ((2n - 1 - x) / n) * P(n-1) - ((n - 1) / n) * P(n-2)
```

I believe there is an error in my implementation, because for some reason the coefficents I get seem way too big. This is the output this program generates:

```
a1 = -190.234
a2 = -295.833
a3 = 378.283
a4 = -939.537
a5 = 774.861
a6 = -400.612
```

Description of code (given below):

If you scroll the code down a little to the part where I declare array, you'll find given x's and y's.

The function polynomial just fills an array with values of said polynomial for certain x. It's a recursive function. I believe it works well, because I have checked the output values.

The gauss function finds coefficents by performing Gaussian elimination on output array. I think this is where the problems begin. I am wondering, if there's a mistake in this code or perhaps my method of veryfying results is bad? I am trying to verify them like that:

```
-190.234 * 1.5 ^ 5 - 295.833 * 1.5 ^ 4 ... - 400.612 = -3017,817625 =/= 2
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double polynomial(int i, int j, double **tab)
{
    double n = i;
    double **array = tab;
    double x = array[j][0];

    if (i == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (i == 1) {
        return 1 - x;
    } else {
        double minusone = polynomial(i - 1, j, array);
        double minustwo = polynomial(i - 2, j, array);
        double result = (((2.0 * n) - 1 - x) / n) * minusone - ((n - 1.0) / n) * minustwo;
        return result;
    }
}

int gauss(int n, double tab[6][7], double results[7])
{
    double multiplier, divider;

    for (int m = 0; m <= n; m++)
    {
        for (int i = m + 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            multiplier = tab[i][m]; 
            divider = tab[m][m];

            if (divider == 0) {
                return 1;
            }

            for (int j = m; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (i == n) {
                    break;
                }

                tab[i][j] = (tab[m][j] * multiplier / divider) - tab[i][j];
            }

            for (int j = m; j <= n; j++) {
                tab[i - 1][j] = tab[i - 1][j] / divider;
            }
        }
    }

    double s = 0;
    results[n - 1] = tab[n - 1][n];
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        s = 0;
        y++;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            s = s + (tab[i][n - 1 - x] * results[n-(x + 1)]); 

            if (y == x + 1) { 
                break;
            }
        }
        results[i] = tab[i][n] - s;
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num;
    double **array;

    array = new double*[5];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new double[2];
    }
                         //i         0      1       2       3       4       5
    array[0][0] = 1.5;  //xi         1.5    2       2.5     3.5     3.8     4.1
    array[0][1] = 2;    //yi         2      5       -1      0.5     3       7
    array[1][0] = 2;
    array[1][1] = 5;
    array[2][0] = 2.5;
    array[2][1] = -1;
    array[3][0] = 3.5;
    array[3][1] = 0.5;
    array[4][0] = 3.8;
    array[4][1] = 3;
    array[5][0] = 4.1;
    array[5][1] = 7;

    double W[6][7]; //n + 1

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            W[i][j] = polynomial(j, i, array);
        }
        W[i][6] = array[i][1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
        {
            cout << W[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    double results[6];
    gauss(6, W, results);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "a" << i + 1 << " = " << results[i] << endl;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your interpretation of the recursive polynomial generation either needs revising or is a bit too clever for me.

given P[0][5] = {1,0,0,0,0,...};  P[1][5]={1,-1,0,0,0,...};
then P[2] is    a*P[0] + convolution(P[1], { c, d });
  where a = -((n - 1) / n)
   c = (2n - 1)/n and d=  - 1/n

This can be generalized: P[n] == a*P[n-2] + conv(P[n-1], { c,d });
In every step there is involved a polynomial multiplication with (c + d*x), which increases the degree by one (just by one...) and adding to P[n-1] multiplied with a scalar a.

Then most likely the interpolation factor x is in range [0..1].

(convolution means, that you should implement polynomial multiplication, which luckily is easy...)

```
              [a,b,c,d]
                * [e,f]
        ------------------
           af,bf,cf,df  +
        ae,be,ce,de, 0  +
--------------------------
 (= coefficients of the final polynomial)
```

Comment: This solution seems smart, however the given task is a homework and I'm afraid this method wouldn't be allowed.. However, I might try it if if I won't figure out anything

Comment: Well, good luck, as the math in laguerro-gauss *interpolation* outsmarts me 100:1. This is just the Laguerro polynomial I'm rambling about.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `P1(x) = x - 1` is not implemented as stated.  You have `1 - x` in the computation.

I did not look any further.

Comment: Sorry! I mixed it up while posting! However, the 1 - x version in the code was right, so the problem remains